# Using dash instead of point in headers

Tags: xetex, punctuation

How can I set `-` instead of `.` as separator in headers?

```
1 Chap
1-1 Sec
1-2 Sec
1-2-1 SubSec
2 Chap
2-1 Sec
```

I use `XePersian` package. The following does not work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How should subsections be numbered: `1-1.1`, or `1-1-1`? What about subsubsections?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by Marco Daniel, it would be smarter to use

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}
```

to take into account any change in the chapter number display. This leads also to the following remark that if you also want to modify the subsections number (and so on for the lower levels), you can use the generic code:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}
```

A MWE to illustrate the proposed code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image: Output2]

**EDIT** I have been asked to extend this answer for having the same behaviour for the figures and tables. Here is the solution (same trick as for the sections and subsections)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter-\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{FooBar}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Baz}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `float` package is used only to have all the float on the same page for a clearer output:

[image: Output for tables and figures]

Comment: I think `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}` should be recommended. So any modification of the counter `chapter` is available for section.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks for the tip, see my edit.

Comment: @LudovicC. Can you please extend you answer for figurers and tables number?

Comment: @PHPst See my edit. Is it what you were looking for (Do not forget to invert `thechapter` and the `\arabic{}` commands to get them in the desired order cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138683/31058)

Answer (score 4):

if you use `xepersian` package, the better way is to set `SepMark` as follows:

```
\usepackage{xepersian}
\SepMark{-}
```

This way the direction of the numbers is also kept!

Answer (score 1):

Using this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139684/13747

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bidi}
\SepMark{-}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{FooBar}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Baz}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```