# Could not change level separator

Tags: punctuation, xepersian

When I use XePersian package the following code does not work to set `-` instead of `.` as separator in headers?

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ofcourse Ludovic's answer is correct, `bidi` defines `\thesection` and similar counter values like this:

```
\thechapter\@SepMark\@arabic\c@section
```

and provides a command `\SepMark` to redefine the separator mark, and use it in all other counter values. So, it is logical to use

```
\SepMark{-}
```

instead of redefining each counter value separately.

Answer (score 5):

You should load the `xepersian` package before the `\renewcommand`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

The above MWE produces the following output:

[image: Output]

And this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{\lr{First}}

\section{\lr{Test}}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: Output2]

**NOTE** As specified in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138664/31058) I made to your previous question, it is said that using `\thechapter` is better than `\arabic{chapter}` and a solution is provided to also have the dash for the subsection numbers.

**EDIT** To get the correct order for the numbers (from right to left) you just need to invert the chapter and section number in the command:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}-\thechapter}
```

The same goes for the subsections.

Comment: Today I'm feeling like that I'm slow as a turtle writing down answers...

Comment: @AndreaL. Some days it is harder than other... Sorry ;)

Comment: Yeah, but the most important thing is someone's issue has been cleared `:-)`.

Comment: There is a problem. As an example, The code also causes the number of second section in chapter one be numbered `1-2`, but in Persian it should be `1-2` (from right to left).

Comment: @PHPst See my edit to solve this trouble...

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't have the problem of order, then what is wrong with that?